# JSON as variable in Angular factory

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, json

I'm kind of newbie to Angular and i'm trying to set the DATA (script.js file)varible to get data from JSON file (books.json). i review a couple of posts but i couldn't understand how it could be applied in a factory kind of structure.

Thanks Ahead !
[Plunker-Code](https://embed.plnkr.co/vuMzAxtDhJ7ZnYls32rO/)

Comment: You can do a couple of things:
1. In your route, add a resolve to call the getBooks function in your service, and in the $http callback, assign your response to the service.data object.

2. You can call the getBooks function in your controller and in your callback assign the books to your controller object.

Either way, your service.getBooks function should use $http.get('books.json');

Comment: So far i understood how to apply it on the module, https://embed.plnkr.co/vuMzAxtDhJ7ZnYls32rO/ but not on the controller

Comment: @user3387719 Your plunker links don't work

Comment: how about now ?  https://embed.plnkr.co/vuMzAxtDhJ7ZnYls32rO/

Answer (score 0):

`$http.get` returns a promise. Return the promise from your factory and then resolve it in your controller using `then`.

In your factory

```
app.factory("bookService", ["$rootScope","$http", 
function($rootScope,$http,$q) {
    var getBooks = function(){
      return $http.get('books.json'); // returns a promise
    }

  return {
    getBooks: getBooks
  };

}]);
```

And in you controller

```
app.controller("listController", ["$scope", "$location", "$routeParams", "bookService",
  function($scope, $location, $routeParams, bookService) {

    bookService.getBooks().then(function(data){ // resolve promise using then()
      // successcallback
      $scope.books = data;
    });
  }
]);
```

Comment: sjokkogutten - Thanks for your time, unfortunately i still can't get the Json file, i did as you instruct me, i get an error that the SVC variable is Unreachable , due to the [ Return {  getBooks: getBooks };]. here is my progression so far. https://embed.plnkr.co/vuMzAxtDhJ7ZnYls32rO/

Comment: I do not have permission to save you Plunk, but you need to 1) add this return statement in your factory `return {
    getBooks: getBooks
  };` 2) include this in you controller: `$scope.books = data;` 3) call `books` on your html

Comment: Hi - sorry for the delay, Here is my code, with edit permissions https://embed.plnkr.co/sioHkk/

Comment: Nope, still dont have edit permissions. But you are almost there. Try to remove `return svc` from your factory.

Comment: did you tried to view the file within Plunker? i've tried from another computer and editing is available... i tried remove the 'rerturn svc' - but nothing is changed... i tried to minimize the code and comment all the extra function (save, edit,etc') and still nothing. the XHR log show that the json file passed with no errors... so it must be something regarding the extraction of the data

Comment: Did you  add `{{books}}` to your HTML? I get it to work from my computer

Comment: Yeah, i can see the Data, wonder why it's not appears as NG-VIEW... Thanks !

Comment: Not quite... Can't make the json data parse into the ng-view.. I guess there is still a problem in getting the data from the json since i can't adressing a properties from the json file -index.html -> {{books.title}} for example - doesn't retrive any data...

Comment: Your json returns an array, so the easiest is to simply use `ng-repeat` to access the properties you need. I've updated the plunkr.

Comment: Sorry Mate, didn't saw it on Plunker..... i'll dig in myself and try to handle with what you explain to me so far....

Comment: GOT IT!!! since the JSON array is stored in var = data - it has to be initiate  - so i simply add to the ng-repeat  books.data  https://embed.plnkr.co/Up4LUP/